# Oracle ILOM CLI access

Tags: powershell, command-line, ssh, putty

I am trying to access an Oracle ILOM interface via command line to read the event log.
As far as I know there are several ways to do this, but none work for me and my environment:

- IPMItools: seems to be available only for Linux or on the CD/DVD that originally came with the server, which of course was lost;
- SSH access (via putty) works fine, but I could not figure a way to automate logging in, running a command on the remote server and reading the result (still looking into it);
- command line SSH access via plink works fine, but as soon as I try adding a command to run on the server (e.g. plink.exe -l root -pw password FQDN help) I get the error message "shell: Invalid credentials". adding the -t option did not change anything;
- the [SSH.NET library for powershell](http://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/SSH_from_PowerShell_using_the_SSH.NET_library) fails with the following exception "Exception calling "Connect" with "0" argument(s): "No suitable authentication method found to complete authentication". Documentation suggests adding a generated public RSA key to the server to allow for possword-less login. That cannot be done on Sun ILOMs;
- Connecting via a serial port as detailed [here](http://practical-admin.com/blog/?p=1227) does not work for me. I must be missing something from the posted code, but I simply cannot open a connection.

Has anyone ever tried to access an ILOM from command line? Could anyone offer a pointer as to what might work?
Ideally I'd like to automate this in a powershell script to be run from a Windows machine, but I'm open to any suggestions that do not require Visual Studio to implement.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Wouldn't it fall under scripting, and therefore Stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0):

ipmi and ssh remote command only supports in ilom3.0+.
if you are using alom, ilom2.0, or sxcf, you won't be able to use these tools.

I'd recommand to use python with pexpect https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/.

check my snippet https://gist.github.com/happlebao/ca143cf3feaf60ca8ef75f7a66cf8a8a